# Proving that something is bounded and monotonic therefore converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So my question is very simple guys,
In order to prove convergence proving that the sequence $a_n$ is bounded and increasing/decreasing is enough, by monotonic sequence property.

Q1) Let's say $a_n$ is bounded below by $0$. And it is a decreasing function, can we say that it converges?

Q2) Let's say $a_n$ is bounded below by $0$. And it is an increasing function, can we say that it converges?

Q3) Let's say $a_n$ is bounded above by $1$. And it is a decreasing function, can we say that it converges?

Q4)Let's say $a_n$ is bounded above by $1$. And it is an increasing function, can we say that it converges?

You can see that point of my questions are that trying to understand when $a_n$ is bounded $a_n$

Comment: Yes, no,no, yes. Now try to add some insights of your own. Say, some examples to reinforce/contradict something. For example, what about $\;a_n=n\;$ to rebute something?

Comment: For the second, see that if we start at $a_0=0$ and we go up... forever, then it might not converge.  Same argument for the third question but going down.